# SharePoint WebParts. Attaching to ProteusDebugEngine debugger failed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and SharePoint Foundation 2010. When I debug my VisualWebParts I have some errors:

1. "Attaching to ProteusDebugEngine debugger failed. Invalid pointer."
   [image]
2. "Cannot debug some of the code in process w3wp.exe [process_number]..."
   [image]

Can everyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This is not Sharepoint specific, but a more general visual studio issue. Try seeing if the solution proposed here works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627251/vs-2010-ultimate-attaching-the-proteusdebugengine-debugger-to-process-failed

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution proposed but It doesn't work.